# JRebel on Weblogic - Netbeans

Tags: weblogic, jrebel

When I am deploying my ear application in Netbeans using JRebel I got this message form JRebel:

**ERROR myJRebel licensing has been discontinued for your application server. myJRebel licensing is only allowed for non-commercial development.**

My Application Server is Weblogic. Is there a way to use JRebel for Weblogic?

Thanks for your help guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebLogic is commercial server and therefore using JRebel with myJRebel license on that server is not supported. In that case you need to [purchase](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/buy/) a license.